# Which option to select to temporarily hold branch changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github, github-actions

- I checked out the **Main** branch.
- Created a new branch based on the main branch call **One**.
- Completed the task and checked it back in.
- Did the exact same steps but this time a new branch called **Two**.

Midway through the second task, i realise there is a bug in branch **One**. In Visual Studio 2022 i try and switch to branch One but prompted with 3 options

1. Bring the changes to branch One.
2. Stash the changes.
3. Discard Changes.

I want to temporarily hold branch Two changes, resolve the bug in branch One check it in and then re-open branch Two from where i left off (So no changes are lost).

I'm pretty sure i need to select the second option but ive been bitten with GitHub before where i get myself into a bizarre situation and then i saw another couple of options within the **Commit All** button dropdown which has me confused **Stash All (--include-untracked)** and **Stash All and keep staged (--keep-index)**

Which option should i select so i can temporarily hold my changes until im ready to start the task under branch Two?

Comment: If you commit the changes to branch2, you can revert them later using `git reset HEAD~1` and have your last commit changes back as untracked. You can also choose to stash, switch branch, switch back to branch2, and apply your stash again. All of them will keep your changes somewhere

Comment: I dont know where to look for or how to apply 'git reset HEAD~1' within Visual Studio? I could try the second option but i dont want to make a mess of it, Let me dig around option 2 you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> --include-untracked
>
> When used with the push and save commands, all untracked files are also stashed and then cleaned up with git clean.

> --keep-index
>
> All changes already added to the index are left intact.

- Whichever option you choose, all changes in branch **Two** will be save in the stash, you can pop them later.
- If changed files have been added into the change index, Choosing `--keep-index` will leave them intact in the working directory, unindexed changed files are always reverted.

Comment: Whilst searching around i decided to go with option 2 (Stash the changes).... went to another branch did some work but when i switched back to the branch that i stashed i cant find those changes. Any idea what i may need to click?

Comment: Run `git stash pop` when you on branch Two.

Comment: Im afraid i dont see that option but i am using Visual Studio 2022.... Is there an equivalent option?

Comment: Git > Commit or Stash... > expand Stashes > right click > Pop > Pop and Restore Staged